# Why does this code crash while testing stack?

Tags: c++, stack, runtime-error

OK, so I edited my code, but I still have two problems :

But here's my code first :

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct stack
{
    int data[5];
    int top;
};

void push (int a, stack &S)
{
    S.top++;

    if (S.top<5)
    {
        S.data[S.top]=a;
    }
    else cout<<"Stack is full!!!"<<endl; S.top--;
}


int pop(stack &S)
{
    if (S.top==-1)
    {
        cout<<"Stack is empty!"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int temp=S.data[S.top];
        S.data[S.top]=NULL;
        S.top--;
        return temp;
    }
}

bool isEMPTY(stack &S)
{
    if (S.top==-1)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
bool isFULL(stack &S)
{
    if (S.top==5)
        return true;
    else return false;
}


int main()
{
    stack S = { {}, -1 };

    push(5,S); cout<<"5 is pushed \n"<<endl;
    push(3,S); cout<<"3 is pushed \n"<<endl;
    push(1,S); cout<<"1 is pushed \n"<<endl;
    push(2,S); cout<<"2 is pushed \n"<<endl;
    push(6,S); cout<<"6 is pushed \n"<<endl;
    push(7,S); cout<<"7 is pushed \n"<<endl;

    cout<<pop(S)<<"is popped\n"<<endl;
    cout<<pop(S)<<"is popped\n"<<endl;
    cout<<pop(S)<<"is popped\n"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, the first problem is, when I pop I get a "Totally random value" and it's not like LIFO.

Second is, I actually intended on inserting 6 values, when I already had the max value = 5, so the output actually showed me the 6 values.

Comment: Look at the value of `s.top` when you're debugging.

Answer (score 2):

```
stack S;
```

Since `stack` is POD, the above line doesn't initialize the member `top`. As such, using  an uninitialized `top` in `push` and `pop` functions invokes undefined behavior.

Write this:

```
stack S {}; //must be compiled in C++11 mode, else write : stack S = stack();
```

This value-initializes `S` and its members, which means, `top` is initialized to `0`. The rest of the code may still have other problems, but at least you have fixed the issues with proper initialization. **If you work with `0` as initial value of `top`, you've write the  logic of `push` and `pop` accordingly!**

Once you fix that, check the value of `top` before *pushing* and *poping* values from the stack, as the member array can have at most `5` elements, and you cannot pop more elements when it is empty. You must maintain these invariants.

Comment: When I tried to do this, it gave me a redline under the first " { " saying : expected a ";" .

Comment: And how to check the value of top in main ?

Comment: It is invalid definition if an object of type stack because according to the logic top should be initialized as -1. I showed the correct definition in my post.:)

Comment: @user3054349: You should check `top` in `push()` and `pop()` functions, not outside them.

Comment: I already did so, in the function itself for push() and pop() each one alone, I had a condition for the function.

Comment: And when I try to pop, it gives me some value as : 948394829 is popped.

Comment: @user3054349: I'll not explain that part. Debug your code. Use `cout` to print the value of `top` every time you `push` and `pop` an element, see if its value makes sense. See when things dont make sense. Try to run the code in your brain. You have to THINK A LOT to make your code perfect.

Comment: Ok, so I ran the code 'In my Brain', and it makes SENSE.

But when I tried to trace the value of top, I found it doesn't change, so it's like I didn't even do anything, and the top doesn't store.

So the error here is in the code, not in my logic.

I'm new to programming, please help.

Comment: Use `cout` in `push` and `pop` to print `top` and other values. I can fix the issue, but that would be useless for you. I can tell you how you can debug your code *yourself* without *requiring* anyone fixing the issue for you.

Comment: Sir, I'm confused about this whole thing, it's that I already have issues with the basics, so please at least let me know how can I fix the syntax.

Comment: @user3054349: You need a BOOK to know the basics and the syntax. It is very frustrating to teach the *basics* online in such forum. If your code doesn't compile, search for the error, and know what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the name of the book that can help me ?!

Comment: @user3054349: Buy any introductory book from this list : [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)... I would suggest **C++ Primer** by ***Stanley Lippman, Josée Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo***.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where an object of type stack was created and how data member top was initialized.
Also take nto account that member function push does not check whether there is an attempt to add an item beyond the array.

You should define the object the following way

```
stack S = { {}, -1 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 else cout<<"Stack is full!!!"<<endl; S.top--;
```

is identical to :

```
else
{
cout<<"Stack is full!!!"<<endl;
} 
S.top--;
```

as a general rule, try to avoid: writing if/else without curly brackets, and, avoid writing more then one line of code in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is:

1. stack s;//you define the local variable "s" without been intitialized.
2. push(5,s);//pass the uninlitialized "s" to the function "push",when debugging your code,"s.top" is not a expected "-1",but some value incredible~(often extreamly larger than 5),so your push operation failed!

```
stack S;
S.top = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    S.data[i] = 0;
}
```